# Selendroid jump start

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selendroid

I just switched from HtmlUnit to Selendroid, because HtmlUnit doesn't work under Android. But I really don't understand selenium/selendroid.

So I got this code:

```
WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();
driver.get("www.google.com");
```

And this Exception, which points on the first line:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.muco.villagedefender, PID: 10430
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriverService
  at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.<init>(EdgeDriver.java:98)
  at com.example.muco.villagedefender.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:85)
  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
  at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:104)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19330)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

On HtmlUnit I just did this and everthing was fine:

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.EDGE);
final HtmlPage page= webClient.getPage("www.google.com");
```

So what is wrong?

The other question: Is there no Selenium/Selendroid doc? I can't find anything, only [this](http://selendroid.io/native.html).

Answer (score 0):

Check your transitive dependencies and make sure you are including:

```
org.seleniumhq.selenium / selenium-edge-driver
```

which - for 2.48.0 and later - should be pulled in automatically by:

```
org.seleniumhq.selenium / selenium-java
```

Also check that the versions match.

Finally, the [docs](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/edge/EdgeDriver.html) suggest you should consider:

```
EdgeDriverService service = new EdgeDriverService.Builder()
     .usingDriverExecutable(new File("path/to/my/MicrosoftWebDriver.exe"))
     .usingAnyFreePort()
     .build();
service.start();

WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(service.getUrl(), DesiredCapabilities.edge());
driver.get("www.google.com");
```

At the moment you're not configuring the EdgeDriver service at all.

Comment: Added : `compile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:2.48.0'
    compile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-edge-driver:2.48.0'` but now i get this : `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/commons/io/ByteOrderMark.class`

Comment: Sounds like this is all about a conflict in your Gradle dependencies. Can you post full list of deps? Also use latest Selenium (2.52) just in case.

Comment: my [build.gradle](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CR7D7.png) and the [External Libs](http://i.stack.imgur.com/w4e5g.png). I wanted to see if selenium works on android, but i don't know how to delete these afterwards.

Comment: Are you using Gradle 2.1? https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/issues/365 suggests there's an underlying issue with Gradle and commons-io, so it seems you may have to exclude it. This is annoying, though it's Gradle vs Android, nothing to do with Selenium, or that invalidates Selenium/Selendroid running on Android.

Comment: I'm using 2.8 . Are these dependencies the right ones? Because it loads for example the **htmlunit** lib, which is not supported by android. And the  String contains **seleniumhq**, i need something like **org.openqa.selenium** because the import of selendroid looks like this, am i wrong?

Comment: Yes, the `groupId` is correct, it doesn't have to match package. HtmlUnit driver is included in main release, and that'll pull in htmlunit, though you don't care if you don't use it. BTW You might as well try 2.52.0 rather than old 2.48.0.

Comment: I changed it now to 2.52.0 . I'm getting this error: `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/thoughtworks/selenium/**BrowserConfigurationOptions.class**` . Everytime i run my project, the class changes and **gradlew clean** doesnt help. My build.gradle looks like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gpaPE.png) at the moment.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Gradle well enough to help you dig deeper into your build problem. It probably wouldn't take long to create a simple Maven project and see if that's better?

Comment: Nevermind, really thanks for your help, i give selendroid up at this point.

Comment: @Muco Question. Is there a specific reason you have to use the edge driver?  Just wondering. Wouldn't it be better just to use the selendroid driver?

What did you want to test? An hybrid app or Mobile browsers?

Comment: @MadisKangro Yes. Before selendroid, i used the HtmlUnit. All the other drivers cried about the sourcecode of the website, which i wanted to inspect. I dont want to test anything. I need some live-information from the  page(uses tons of javascript). With HtmlUnit everything was already done, but i dont understand selenium/selendroid.

Comment: @Muco I'm still confused. I mean you can use selendroid to gather live data from a website, but I'm having troubles trying to figure out your workflow. Let me ask a couple of questions.
1. Why do you want to use selendroid? Selendroid is ment for android UI automation.  HtmlUnit would be much faster if you want to get some information, hence the question. Why would you want to run it on selendroid. (You can do it, it just isn't the best in terms of performance)
2. Do you want to use the live data right away somewhere else?

Comment: @MadisKangro 1. I dont actually want to, but HtmlUnit doesnt work under android as i wrote. My code in HtmlUnit is pretty done. 2. I will use the data in my app.

Comment: @Muco What do you plan to do with the app? I think that selendroid won't work like how you want it to work. The implementation of selendroid is quite different.

Comment: @MadisKangro i want to run the function, which gets the live-data from the website, after a specific time and use the data afterwards

Comment: @Muco I would look into something else than selendroid. Selendroids idea is completely different what you want to achieve.Selendroid is a test automation framework which drives off the UI of Android native and hybrid applications. I think what you want is completely different. I'm assuming the live-data you are trying to gather isn't from your website?

Comment: @MadisKangro no its from another website.